# Align Bootstrap Heading and Caption to Top Left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel, heading

I am trying to get the heading, caption and selector elements of a Bootstrap carousel to align to the left and then spread evenly from top to bottom. So the heading would be at the top, the caption after that, the link to the page and then the selectors at the bottom.

Below is a link to a mockup of what I'm trying to accomplish.
www.askmestudios.com/files/capture.jpg

Below is a link for what is happening with the given code.
www.askmestudios.com/files/capture3.jpg

So far I can align the heading and caption to the left but can't make much happen after that. I've tried absolute position and it's not very responsive friendly. I'm sorry for the limited code but nothing I tried made much of a difference.

```
<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"><img src="img.jpg" alt="First slide image" class="center-block">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-hdr">First slide Heading</h3>
        <p class="p-hdr">First slide Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.h3-hdr {
  text-align: left;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}
.p-hdr {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Where is your custom css placed inside the header tags? It should be placed after bootstrap for the classes to be able to be overridden.

Comment: It is, I've updated the code with the links in the header.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what Is happening

Comment: Yes, it's now in the original post. I'm also trying to get it further to the left.